# Should I use で or に in 「最近新しい医学の論文をアメリカの雑誌　で/に　読みました」?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-で

I'm not sure if  should use で or に in this sentence

> 最近新しい医学の論文をアメリカの雑誌　で/に　読みました。

I would go with に, do you agree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「最近{さいきん}新{あたら}しい医学{いがく}の論文{ろんぶん}をアメリカの雑誌{ざっし}　で/に　読{よ}みました。」

That should be 「で」 for nearly all occasions today.

Using 「に」 there would make it sound unnecessarily "literary" and/or "quaint".  Unless you can write the whole composition, essay, etc. in that style, I would not recommend writing only one of the sentences like that.

Do the whole piece in your particular style and your readers will recognize (and appreciate) it as a style.  Do it sporadically and they will only think you made mistakes.  The difference is huge.